# Vue JS and model binding in tables

Tags: javascript, vue.js

why is it not possible to bind a model via v-model within a table like this:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Responder ID</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="responder in responders">
            <td v-model="selected" @click="selectResponder(responder)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></span></td>
            <td>@{{ responder.userReference }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to achieve, that when the user clicks a glyphicon in a table row, the selected element is bind to the variable in my javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v-model` is used to bind a variable to any type of form input, and doesn't apply to a `<td>` element. Your @click method can do what you are describing though:

```
//in your Vue instance
...
methods:{
    selectResponder(responder){
        //either...
        responder.selected = true;

        //or maybe...
        this.selected = responder;
    }
}
...
```